# Use PowerShell to unpin Taskbar shortcut depending on shortcut Target Path

Tags: windows, powershell, taskbar, shortcut, pins

Having an issue with some PowerShell. Basically I am trying to remove certain Taskbar shortcuts based on the shortcuts path/exe file.

The following code I have gets the pinned shortcuts and their name from the AppData folder:

```
Function Get-TaskbarShortcuts
{
Begin{
  Clear-Host
        $Path = "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar"
        $x=0
      } # End of Begin

Process
    {
        $TaskbarShortcuts = Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse -Include *.lnk
            ForEach($ShortCut in $TaskbarShortcuts)
            {
                $Shell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell 
                    $Properties = @{
                    ShortcutName = $Shortcut.Name 
                    LinkTarget = $Shell.CreateShortcut($Shortcut).targetpath 
                                    }
                New-Object PSObject -Property $Properties 
                $x ++
                Write-Host $ShortCut
            } #End of ForEach
        [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Shell) | Out-Null
    } # End of Process
  End{}
}
```

I need to amend this code to remove certain shortcuts...say for example, a user has pinned 'C:\Windows\notepad.exe' but called the shortcut Name something odd. How would I remove the actual pin from the taskbar (not just delete the shortcut file)?

Comment: You won't find an officially supported solution to this.  Microsoft intentionally made it difficult to programmatically modify the pinned items on the taskbar.  In WinXP, a lot of installers would add their own icon to the quicklaunch and then remove their competitors' icons.  MS wanted to avoid that with the Win7 taskbar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Deleting the shortcut from the "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar" leaves the icon on the taskbar but in an unusable state and clicking it pops up an error that it doesn't exist and asks if you want to remove it.  I'm guessing that this is what you want to avoid.

There doesn't seem to be a simple way to do this, but there's a Module available in the TechNet Script Center that does the trick:

[Pin and unpin applications from the taskbar and Start-menu](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/b66434f1-4b3f-4a94-8dc3-e406eb30b750/)

```
###########################################################################" 
 #  
 # 
 # NAME: PinnedApplications.psm1 
 #  
 # AUTHOR: Jan Egil Ring, Crayon 
 # 
 # DATE  : 06.08.2010  
 #  
 # COMMENT: Module with the ability to pin and unpin programs from the taskbar and the Start-menu in Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2. 
 # 
 # This module are based on the Add-PinnedApplication script created by Ragnar Harper and Kristian Svantorp: 
 # http://blogs.technet.com/kristian/archive/2009/04/24/nytt-script-pin-to-taskbar.aspx 
 # http://blog.crayon.no/blogs/ragnar/archive/2009/04/17/pin-applications-to-windows-7-taskbar.aspx 
 # 
 # Johan Akerstrom`s blog: http://cosmoskey.blogspot.com 
 # 
 # For more information, see the following blog post: 
 # http://blog.crayon.no/blogs/janegil/archive/2010/02/26/pin-and-unpin-applications-from-the-taskbar-and-start-menu-using-windows-powershell.aspx 
 # 
 # VERSION HISTORY: 
 # 1.0 17.04.2009 - Initial release by Ragnar Harper and Kristian Svantorp 
 # 1.1 26.02.2010 - Update by Jan Egil Ring. Added the capability to unpin applications. 
 # 1.2 06.08.2010 - Update by Johan Akerstrom. Added full MUI support. 
 #  
 ###########################################################################" 


function Set-PinnedApplication 
{ 
<#  
.SYNOPSIS  
This function are used to pin and unpin programs from the taskbar and Start-menu in Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 
.DESCRIPTION  
The function have to parameteres which are mandatory: 
Action: PinToTaskbar, PinToStartMenu, UnPinFromTaskbar, UnPinFromStartMenu 
FilePath: The path to the program to perform the action on 
.EXAMPLE 
Set-PinnedApplication -Action PinToTaskbar -FilePath "C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe" 
.EXAMPLE 
Set-PinnedApplication -Action UnPinFromTaskbar -FilePath "C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe" 
.EXAMPLE 
Set-PinnedApplication -Action PinToStartMenu -FilePath "C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe" 
.EXAMPLE 
Set-PinnedApplication -Action UnPinFromStartMenu -FilePath "C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe" 
#>  
       [CmdletBinding()] 
       param( 
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Action,  
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$FilePath 
       ) 
       if(-not (test-path $FilePath)) {  
           throw "FilePath does not exist."   
    } 

       function InvokeVerb { 
           param([string]$FilePath,$verb) 
        $verb = $verb.Replace("&","") 
        $path= split-path $FilePath 
        $shell=new-object -com "Shell.Application"  
        $folder=$shell.Namespace($path)    
        $item = $folder.Parsename((split-path $FilePath -leaf)) 
        $itemVerb = $item.Verbs() | ? {$_.Name.Replace("&","") -eq $verb} 
        if($itemVerb -eq $null){ 
            throw "Verb $verb not found."             
        } else { 
            $itemVerb.DoIt() 
        } 

       } 
    function GetVerb { 
        param([int]$verbId) 
        try { 
            $t = [type]"CosmosKey.Util.MuiHelper" 
        } catch { 
            $def = [Text.StringBuilder]"" 
            [void]$def.AppendLine('[DllImport("user32.dll")]') 
            [void]$def.AppendLine('public static extern int LoadString(IntPtr h,uint id, System.Text.StringBuilder sb,int maxBuffer);') 
            [void]$def.AppendLine('[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]') 
            [void]$def.AppendLine('public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string s);') 
            add-type -MemberDefinition $def.ToString() -name MuiHelper -namespace CosmosKey.Util             
        } 
        if($global:CosmosKey_Utils_MuiHelper_Shell32 -eq $null){         
            $global:CosmosKey_Utils_MuiHelper_Shell32 = [CosmosKey.Util.MuiHelper]::LoadLibrary("shell32.dll") 
        } 
        $maxVerbLength=255 
        $verbBuilder = new-object Text.StringBuilder "",$maxVerbLength 
        [void][CosmosKey.Util.MuiHelper]::LoadString($CosmosKey_Utils_MuiHelper_Shell32,$verbId,$verbBuilder,$maxVerbLength) 
        return $verbBuilder.ToString() 
    } 

    $verbs = @{  
        "PintoStartMenu"=5381 
        "UnpinfromStartMenu"=5382 
        "PintoTaskbar"=5386 
        "UnpinfromTaskbar"=5387 
    } 

    if($verbs.$Action -eq $null){ 
           Throw "Action $action not supported`nSupported actions are:`n`tPintoStartMenu`n`tUnpinfromStartMenu`n`tPintoTaskbar`n`tUnpinfromTaskbar" 
    } 
    InvokeVerb -FilePath $FilePath -Verb $(GetVerb -VerbId $verbs.$action) 
} 

Export-ModuleMember Set-PinnedApplication
```

Comment: Yeh, I was trying to avoid the error you have mentioned. Thanks for this, I will give the module a try :)

Comment: Confirmed that `Set-PinnedApplication -Action UnPinFromTaskbar -FilePath "C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe"` removes notepad from my taskbar.

Comment: Does this work for UWP apps? How do you get the path?

Comment: Anyone figured out how to do this for UWP apps?