# Unpin Taskbar Item in Windows 10 with Powershell

Tags: powershell, taskbar

I try to unpin Internet Explorer from the taskbar with Powershell.

Taskbar.reg is the Taskband Folder from the Registry, without IE.
After executing the Icon is still there and works, but when Rightclicking, I get the option to pin it to the taskbar instead of unpinning it

```
reg import C:\Users\USER\Taskbar.reg
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25041205/use-powershell-to-unpin-taskbar-shortcut-depending-on-shortcut-target-path

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use PowerShell to unpin Taskbar shortcut depending on shortcut Target Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25041205/use-powershell-to-unpin-taskbar-shortcut-depending-on-shortcut-target-path)

Answer (score 0):

To do it in PowerShell without working with the registery would be to use this: [Pin and unpin applications from the taskbar and Start-menu](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/b66434f1-4b3f-4a94-8dc3-e406eb30b750/).

Once downloaded save it to the same directory and use, for example:

```
Import-Module './downloaded_script.ps1'

 Set-PinnedApplication -Action UnPinFromTaskbar -FilePath "C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe"
```

Comment: Great for Windows 7 and server 2008 r2 but the OP is looking for Windows 10.  And for that this does not work.